# Left join conditionally on timestamps in pd.merge_asof(...)

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

I have two dataframes that I would like left join based on proximity of timestamps. I would like to use pd.merge_asof(...) to do this but it seems like that function only joins to the nearest row in the right dataframe, and I would like for each row in the right dataframe to join to the left based on proximity to the left dataframe's timestamp.

For example:

```
df1:
     TS1                    id1
1    2019-08-15 16:45:00    1
2    2019-08-15 17:00:00    2
3    2019-08-15 17:15:00    3

df2:
     TS2                    id2
1    2019-08-15 16:45:00    1
2    2019-08-15 16:45:00    2
3    2019-08-15 16:46:00    3
4    2019-08-15 17:00:00    4
5    2019-08-15 17:01:00    5
6    2019-08-15 17:15:00    6
```

What I have tried:

```
test = pd.merge_asof(
    df1.sort_values('TS1'), 
    df2.sort_values('TS2'), 
    left_on='TS1', 
    right_on='TS2', 
    direction='forward'
)
```

Which gives:

```
     TS1                    TS2                    id1    id2
1    2019-08-15 16:45:00    2019-08-15 16:45:00    1      1
2    2019-08-15 17:00:00    2019-08-15 17:00:00    2      4
3    2019-08-15 17:15:00    2019-08-15 17:15:00    3      6
```

What I would like to see is:

```
     TS1                    TS2                    id1    id2
1    2019-08-15 16:45:00    2019-08-15 16:45:00    1      1
2    2019-08-15 16:45:00    2019-08-15 16:45:00    1      2
3    2019-08-15 16:45:00    2019-08-15 16:46:00    1      3
4    2019-08-15 17:00:00    2019-08-15 17:00:00    2      4
5    2019-08-15 17:00:00    2019-08-15 17:01:00    2      5
6    2019-08-15 17:15:00    2019-08-15 17:15:00    3      6
```

I know that I could loop over each dataframe to make up an id and use that to make the join work.  Is there a cleaner way to do this (preferably using existing functions)?

Comment: If i had to sum this up - you want to join `df1` and `df2` on similar timestamps. If that is true, what is your threshold for "similar timestamps"?

Comment: `asof` is a 1:1 merge, you can't get a 1:many. You *could* do the full cartesian join then susbet afterwards, but that can be very memory inefficient.

Comment: There is a column in the left table that has a value in seconds that defines a window.  But I would be fine if it just used the p.merge_asof(...) logic and joined on every nearest timestamp in the forward direction until there was a next nearest timestamp.

Comment: Sounds like maybe this would be a good feature request.

Comment: I submitted a feature request: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28578.  We'll see what happens.